# Limit of a Symmetric Random Walk

Tags: limits, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, random-walk, central-limit-theorem

I'm given a probability space of ($\Omega$, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P}$) and am asked to look into a symmetric random walk with its n-step defined as

$$
X_k = \Bigg\{ 
\begin{matrix} 
1 & \text{with probability 1/2} \\
-1 & \text{with probability 1/2}
\end{matrix}
$$

where $X_n$ and $X_m$ are independent for all $n \ne m$.

$$
S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k, \text{   i = 1, 2, ..., t}
$$

where $S_0 = 0$. Defining

$$
W_t^{(n)}=\frac{S_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor nt \rfloor}X_k
$$

I want to show that for fixed time t

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}W_t^{(n)}
= \frac{S_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}}
= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor nt \rfloor}X_k
\overset{D}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0,t)
$$

I know by the central limit theorem that 
$\frac{X_N}{\sqrt{N}} \overset{D}{\to} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ as $N \to \infty$ and I have found a [lecture](https://www.whoi.edu/fileserver.do?id=21268&pt=10&p=17232) that states

> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{S_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{S_{\lfloor nt \rfloor}}{\sqrt{\lfloor nt \rfloor}}\frac{\sqrt{\lfloor nt \rfloor}}{\sqrt{n}} \to \mathcal{N}(0,1)\sqrt{t} \overset{D}{=} \mathcal{N}(0,t) $$

However, I am confused as to how each step in this equation leads to the other. I'd greatly appreciate if anyone could provide some insight on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution then $Y_{n_k} \to Y$in distribution for any subsequence $\{n_k\}$. Here $\{ {\lfloor {nt} \rfloor}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{1,2,\cdots\}$. Next, $Y_n \to Y$ in distribution and $a_n \to a>0$ implies $a_nY_n \to aY$ in distribution. Finally $\{\sqrt {\lfloor {nt} \rfloor}\}/\sqrt n \to \sqrt  t$ as $n \to \infty$.